# Adobe Sign (Echo Sign) API is only sending document to draft C#

Tags: c#, rest, api, adobe, echosign

I am working with Adobe Sign APIs to send a document for signature using C#.

When I called the API to send the document to its respective recipient, it just saved my document as a draft instead of directly sending my document to the recipient.

Is this the default behavior? Is there any way to send the document to recipient directly?

Answer (score 0):

I forget to add the state parameter and upgraded api end point.

JSON Object:
{"fileInfos":[{"transientDocumentId":"*"}],"name":"","participantSetsInfo":[{"memberInfos":[{"email":""}],"order":1,"role":"SIGNER"}],"signatureType":"ESIGN",**"state":"IN_PROCESS"**}

**State:** IN_PROCESS
**Api End Point**: api/rest/v6/agreements

https://www.adobe.io/apis/documentcloud/sign/docs/#!adobeio/adobeio-documentation/master/sign/api_usage/send_signing.md

Answer (score -1):

Please confirm that your state value should be "IN_PROCESS" instead of "DRAFT".You can aslo concern with this documentation .

https://www.adobe.io/apis/documentcloud/sign/docs.html#!adobedocs/adobe-sign/master/api_usage/send_signing.md